# Make an image fit specific dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

OK, what I need should be pretty easy for anyone having played with that before, so here we are :

- I have images of various dimensions
- The images resolution *is* high
- I want to make them "fit" into - e.g. 150x200px - blocks (of specific dimensions)
- The images should **not** : be stretched, leave white margins around the image (in case of resizing etc)

So, basically, I'm looking for a plugin (preferably jquery), to automatically resize images (based on some `class`?) and do the trick.

Any ideas?

Comment: NailThumb is what you need ,`http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php`

Comment: @dreamweiver Yep, NailThumb **is** what I needed. Exactly what I wanted, buddy! Thanks a lot! :-) (Please, post is as an answer and I will accept it ;-)).

Comment: Your welcome buddy,just close this question by checking the right answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NailThumb is what you need buddy

http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Show it as a `background-image` and include this in your CSS style sheet:

```
 background-size: contain;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Scaling_background_images

Although it is CSS3, It would be the option I would go with.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, as I'm learning JS, I thought I'd see if I could write some code for this. It seems to work, no matter what the dimensions of the div. Not sure how good the JS is, but I thought I'd post it anyhow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

div {width: 200px; height: 150px; overflow: hidden;}
img {width: 100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div><img src="test.png" alt=""></div>

<script>
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (i=0; i<imgs.length; i++) 
{
    var img = imgs[i];
    img.style.width = "auto";
    var p = img.parentNode;
    var h = p.clientHeight;
    var w = p.clientWidth;

    if (img.style.height < h) {
        img.style.height = h + "px";
        img.style.width = ((img.style.width / img.style.height) * h) + "px";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```